# How to install Autobahn with pypy

Tags: python, twisted, pypy

I'm using PyPy 1.8 on Windows, and I tried to install Autobahn. I fired up the interpreter, typed in "import autobahn", it crashed with error message: "Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread pypy..."

Comment: I don't think this belongs here, however I think it's fixed on trunk already.

Comment: @fijal - where does it belong, then?

Comment: pypy bug tracker probably? It seems to be the kind of question that is a problem and then it's fixed, so the question becomes irrelevant

Comment: I posted it on Google groups but haven't seen any reply after 1 week

Comment: Autobahn works with PyPy trunk on Linux and FreeBSD. I haven't tried it on PyPy Windows.